# Where are favored indicators located and how do you interpret them?

Tags: starcraft-2

I read somewhere that, before a game starts, Starcraft 2 shows *"favored indicators"* to indicate whether your opponent is (expected to be) stronger or weaker than you.

Where are these indicators and how do you interpret them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

As you can see the team on the right side is "Slightly Favored."

Favoring is usually a good indicator of how many ladder points you will win:

- Opponent Favored: 20-25
- Opponent Slightly Favored: 15-25
- Even: 10-15
- You Slightly Favored: 5-10
- You Favored: 1-5

Bare in mind these are rough estimates.

In theory Favoring is based on your Hidden Rank.  However, since the points you are awarded are based on your visible rank, it is possible for both sides to be Favored.  This did occur during the beta, but has reportedly been "cleaned up."

Comment: "Hidden" and "visible" rank?

Comment: @BlueRaja you have a visible number of points and you are ranked in your division according to this.  However, blizzard also keeps track of a hidden number (which you can't see) which determines what League you are placed in, as well as, who you are matched against.

Comment: **[Edit]** I had a bunch of questions here, but I will just [ask another question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5773/starcraft-2-hidden-vs-visible-ranking).

Answer (score 0):

It shows during the loading screen, and it's at the bottom of the screen. It only happens during ladder games. It shows a bright light blue bar on one side of the bottom or the other indicating which side is favored. (or a bright bar in the middle of the bottom indicating evenly matched)