# When exactly do players move between leagues?

Tags: starcraft-2

I see [this article](http://starcraft.wikia.com/wiki/League_(StarCraft_II)#cite_note-LadderFAQ-1) that says

```
After a hidden period of time, their skill level will be reevaluated.
```

Has anyone been able to determine how this work? I now reached 1st place in my league and am eager to pass on to the next. I was already promoted a league once, how long do I wait before being promoted again? Does a higher score grant me a better/sooner chance of being upgraded, or does it simply happen at random time period if I have enough score?

Comment: This doesn't answer your literal question, but it may address your underlying eagerness to move up to the next league.  It doesn't matter what league you are in, unless you care about the bragging rights.  You will play opponents that are roughly equal to your skill no matter what league your are in.  I started in bronze, and was playing silver and the occasional gold player before i was promoted.  Then eventually I was playing mostly gold and a few platinum players, though still in silver.  I have since been promoted to gold.

Comment: I then switched my play style from a 5RR early aggression style to a more macro defensive style, and have been losing often enough (hopefully only until i adapt) that I now face some silver opponents again, despite still being in gold.  Try to notice what league you opponents are in.  if they are all in a higher league, or 2 leagues higher, then you will be promoted eventually...

Comment: Just win favored games and you will be promoted quickly enough. Lose favored games is a good way to get demoted!

Answer (score 1):

The score you see doesn't matter and it's mostly there so you feel like you're making progress and hence continue playing.

See [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5773/starcraft-2-hidden-vs-visible-ranking) for more details on that.  I've been told it's evaluated every so many games (I heard 30 before, but I can't say how definite that is).

You'll get promoted faster if you consistently beat players that are ranked higher than you (in the hidden ranking, not the visible points you see)