# What factors are considered when deciding whether someone is favored or not?

Tags: starcraft-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where are favored indicators located and how do you interpret them?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5761/where-are-favored-indicators-located-and-how-do-you-interpret-them)

I tend to play 2v2 or 3v3, with all my team being platinum league. Sometimes, when a match begins, we see our enemies are "favored". At the end of the match, when we take a look at the score screen, our opponent's leagues are gold, and sometimes even silver.

So, what factors are considered when deciding whether someone is favored or not? Because clearly, leagues are not the only variable here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Being favored in any Starcraft II match, has nothing to do with leagues. It all has to to do with the ["Hidden Match Making Rating"](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Battle.net_Leagues#Hidden_.22Matchmaking_Rating.22_.28MMR.29). It determines your actual skill level based off of winning or losing to opponents at, below, or above you current determined skill. As a side note, when you raise your HMMR enough, you will get promoted to the next league.

> Every pair of players is ranked individually. So players A+B's team will have a ranking completely unrelated to players A+C's team. In 2v2 random match-ups, an average rating of the two players will be compared to their opponents rating. This rule presumably applies for 3v3 and 4v4 as well.